# AVR internal EEPROM write function is not working properly

Tags: c, embedded, avr

those are the two functions of read and write

```
////////////EEPROM.c//////////////

void IEEPROM_Write(u16 A_u16Adress, u8 A_u8Data)
{
    /* Wait for completion of previous write */
    while(GET_BIT(EECR,EECR_EEWE)==1);
    /* Set up address and data registers */
    EEAR = A_u16Adress;
    EEDR = A_u8Data;
    /* Write logical one to EEMWE */
    SET_BIT(EECR,EECR_EEMWE);
    /* Start eeprom write by setting EEWE */
    SET_BIT(EECR,EECR_EEWE);
}


u8 IEEPROM_Read(u16 A_u16Adress)
{
    /* Wait for completion of previous write */
    while(GET_BIT(EECR,EECR_EEWE)==1);
    /* Set up address and data registers */
    EEAR = A_u16Adress;
    /* Start eeprom read by setting EERE */
    SET_BIT(EECR,EECR_EERE);

    return EEDR;
}
////////////EEPROM.h//////////////

#define EEARH (*(volatile u8 *)0x3F)
#define EEARL (*(volatile u8 *)0x3E)
#define EEAR (*(volatile u16 *)0x3E)
#define EECR (*(volatile u8 *)0x3C)
#define EECR_EERE 0
#define EECR_EEWE 1
#define EECR_EEMWE 2
#define EECR_EERIE 3

#define EEDR (*(volatile u8 *)0x3D)
void IEEPROM_Write(u16 A_u16Adress, u8 A_u8Data);
u8 IEEPROM_Read(u16 A_u16Adress);
```

I followed the instructions of the ATMEGA32 Datasheet but it the code doesn't work
I write a number on a byte then I read it and display it on LCD , but it prints 255,

Comment: use standard avr heders

Comment: @0___________ I used them and it worked , but I make all the libraries by myself so i can't use avr libraries

Comment: then look insde avr one and see the difference

Comment: @0___________ i tried but the eeprom.h only contains the declaration of the function

Comment: --> Try harder.

Comment: @0___________ try harder ? mmmm.. okay , why didn't you say that from the beginning ?

Comment: @0___________ anyway it is not open source , i can't access the source code

Comment: 1. make sure you use atmega32, not atmega32u4 or other atmega32uX. 2.Does `EEPROM_Read()` return and display correct value if you write it to EEPROM with programmer? 3. How `GET_BIT` and `SET_BIT` are implemented?

Comment: @dimich , iam using atmega 32 , i wrote many drivers using this datasheet  , it display correct value when i use <avr/eeprom.h> library....

and those are the bit math macros
#define SET_BIT(Reg, bitnum)       (Reg |=1<<bitnum)
#define CLR_BIT(Reg, bitnum)       (Reg &=~(1<<bitnum))
#define GET_BIT(Reg, bitnum)       ((Reg>>bitnum)& 0x01)

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim I compared disassembly of your `IEEPROM_Write()` (with `_delay_us(10)` removed) and library function `eeprom_write_byte()`. The only difference, except different general registers usage, is interrupt masking during EECR modification. Do you use interrupts in your program? Are they disabled? How to you invoke `IEEPROM_Write()`? What are compilation flags?

Comment: @dimich no i don't use interrupts , the flag is the write enable , in the main.c the i use the write function like thet ...    IEEPROM_Write(2, 25); .  ...

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim And what if you dump EEPROM with programmer, e.g. `avrdude ... -U eeprom:r:-:h` ?

Comment: @dimich i don't know how to do that

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim what tool to you use for flashing your program to MCU? It shold also have function to dump or inspect EEPROM content. Check what actual EEPROM content is.

Comment: @dimich I use avrdude in eclipse , ok i will try , you noticed that I said that <avr/eeprom.h> works fine right ?

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim As i understand you used `eeprom_write_byte()` and `eeprom_read_byte()` in a pair to check if EEPROM works and value is displayed correctly. Did you try `eeprom_write_byte()`/`IEEPROM_Read()` in a pair? And  `IEEPROM_Write()`/`eeprom_read_byte()`? Maybe the issue is not with your `IEEPROM_Write()` function but with something else.

Comment: It is rare the microcontroller libraries come in the form of object files or linked libs. There's almost always the complete C source for them available somewhere. If you step into the lib functions while debugging, do you see C code or just raw asm? If you see C code then  the C code is present on your computer.

Comment: Also unrelated to the problem, it's standard practice to always compare the value to be written versus what's already stored in the eeprom cells. If it's the same, then don't erase/write. That way you'll save lots of needless memory wear.

Comment: Also unrelated to your actual problem, the defines actually do not belong in the header, but rather at the top of your implementation. The header is your interface to use the IEEPROM_Read/Write functions.

Comment: @dimich fine i will try

Comment: I tried eeprom_write_byte()/IEEPROM_Read() in a pair and it worked fine , but IEEPROM_Write()/eeprom_read_byte() didn't work , so the problem is from the write function

Answer (score 4):

Do not delay between setting `EEMWE` and setting `EEWE`. The data sheet says, emphasis by me:

> When EEMWE is set, setting EEWE **within four clock cycles** will write data to the EEPROM at the selected address. If EEMWE is zero, setting EEWE will have no effect. When EEMWE has been written to one by software, hardware clears the bit to zero after four clock cycles.

---

> *I removed it but still same problem*

Then I assume that `SET_BIT` is a function or macro that takes more than four clock cycles. You might want to edit your question and show us the definition of it.

Replace it with appropriate code, to make sure that it is equivalent to:

```c
    EECR |= 1 << EEMWE;
    EECR |= 1 << EEWE;
```

Of course, no interrupts must occur in between.

The data sheet additionally mentions:

> The EEPROM can not be programmed during a CPU write to the Flash memory. The software must check that the Flash programming is completed before initiating a new EEPROM write.

Therefore it recommends to wait until `SPMEN` in `SPMCR` becomes zero. However, I see this as optional if you are sure that no Flash programming takes place.

Comment: i removed it but still same problem

Comment: To expand on this answer: having other interrupts enabled while running an eeprom driver is a very common cause of problems. Not only may they screw up timing, they might even access the memory you are writing to. I'd add an `asm CLI;` (if I remember AVR ISA correctly) at the start of the eeprom write.

Answer (score 2):

`EECR` register is within the lower IO registers range, which bits can be accessed individually using `sbi` and `cbi` processor instructions.

Operations like `EECR |= 1 << EEMWE` will be compiled as a single bit access. But, according to the datasheet you have to

> 5. Write a logical one to the EEMPE bit while writing a zero to EEPE in EECR.
> 6. Within four clock cycles after setting EEMPE, write a logical one to EEPE.

That means, when `sbi` is used, a zero will not be written to `EEPE`. Instead, use assignment:

`EECR = (EECR & ~(1 << EEPE)) | (1 << EEMPE)`

or simple `EECR = (1 << EEMPE)` (writing zero to all other bits)

Also, as it was noted, setting `EEPE` has to be done within 4 cpu clock cycles.

Here is a working example of EEPROM writing code:

```
void eeprom_write(ee_addr_type addr, uint8_t val) {
  while (EECR & (1 << EEPE)); // wait for the previous EEPROM operation to complete
  uint8_t old_sreg = SREG; // Save flags (including I flag)
  asm volatile("cli":::"memory"); // locking interrupts
  while (EECR & (1 << EEPE)); // just for the case EEPROM operation was started in the interrupt, wait again
  EEAR = addr; 
  EECR |= (1 << EERE); // reading the EEPROM content
  uint8_t d = EEDR;
  if (d != val) { // Programming only if needed
    uint8_t eecr_val;
    if (val == 0xFF) { // If all bits need to be set then 
      eecr_val = (1 << EEPM0); // Erase only mode
    } else if ((d & val) == val) { // If all bits are only changing from 1 to 0 then
      eecr_val = (1 << EEPM1); // Write only mode
    } else {
      eecr_val = 0; // Otherwise erase and write
    }
    EEDR = val;
    EECR = eecr_val | (1<<EEMPE);
    EECR |= (1<<EEPE);
  }
  SREG = old_sreg; // Restoring interrupt flag (enable interrupts only if they were enabled at the beginning)
}
```

this function exits while EEPROM operation is ongoing, you have to check it is done before reading the EEPROM

```
uint8_t eeprom_read(ee_addr_type addr) {
  while(EECR & (1<<EEPE)); // wait for the previous EEPROM operation to complete
  uint8_t old_sreg = SREG;
  asm volatile("cli":::"memory"); // Lock interrupts
  while(EECR & (1<<EEPE)); 
  EEAR = addr;
  EECR |= (1<<EERE);
  uint8_t res = EEDR;
  SREG = old_sreg; // Restore interrupts
  return res;
}
```

Comment: what is EEPM0 and EEPM1 ?

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim (please refer to the datasheet on the MCU) those bits allow to perform erase only (without writing) or writing (without erase) over bits in the EEPROM location. Thus allowing to reduce wear-off of EEPROM resource. For simplicity you can always write them both zero - that will perform full erase-write cycle.

Comment: found them , the read works but the write doesn't

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim make sure you have compilation optimization enabled (at least -o1 level) otherwise the compiler may produce ineffective code, which takes more than 4 cycles